# How can I set up Backbone view events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

The question:
I have a project based on Backbone, Underscore, Browserfy and coffeescript.
There is a view in a project:

```
"use strict"

_             = require "underscore"
$             = require "jquery"
Backbone      = require "backbone"

Works_tpl     = require "modules/works/templates/works_template.coffee"

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend

    el      : ".works-wrapper"
    template: _.template Works_tpl

    events  : {
        "click .change-view__item": "changeView"
    }

    initialize: (works, type = "list")
        @render works, type
        return

    render: (works, type) ->
        @$el.html @template
        return

    changeView: ->
        console.log 123
        return
```

There is a template (underscore template) in a project:

```
"use strict"

module.exports = '
<div class="change-view__item">Нажми на меня</div>
'
```

Rendering is perfectly working, but events (view events) aren't working. Help me please to do it works. Base your answer on my code please.

Comment: Is the missing `->` after `initialize` just a typo? Your code works otherwise (https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2kqp98pk/), can you modify that fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Dispite that, I would absolutely not recommend to call render from initialize, but rather separately. Also return `@` within the render method to support chaining and accessing the views rendered element later like this `view.render().el`